# How to use form-based authentication with jQuery and Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, get, authentication

I am trying to fake bypass the browser basic authentication, and I don't really understand how this works.

I've seen some ways people deal with this basic authentication.

Basically the browser is asking me to enter a username and a password in the very beginning, but I want it to wait until the user enters an username and password in a `<form>...</form>`.

I am actually trying to request some JSON files.

I've seen people using `xhr.setRequestHeader` and/or `ajax {method: GET}`, bu so far nothing worked for me.

How does this really work and in what order?

---

All right, I found my answer with arma's help. The "PUT" command is for modifying something. The "POST" command is for creating/adding something:

```
var mydata = {"fname":"bobworth"};
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    processData : false,
    data: JSON.stringify(mydata),
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://www.example.com/users/",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    username: "mark",
    password: "123456",
    success: function(t){    alert(t);  },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){
        alert("jqXHR:"+jqXHR.status+" txtStatus:"+textStatus+" Error:"+error);  }
});
```

Comment: Are you asking how do you send a username and password to a AUTH'ed directory, or how to emulate the AUTH popup form via jQuery?

Comment: first guess :how do you send a username and password to a AUTH'ed directory

Answer (score 0):

*[Passing http-authenticate credentials to Ext.Ajax or Ext.data.Connection requests?](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?18222-Passing-http-authenticate-credentials-to-Ext.Ajax-or-Ext.data.Connection-requests)* looks like a good starting point.